# String formatting with f-string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just want to do something for transformation my string into view like: (2 ** 5)(5)(7 ** 2)(11), but my code works wrong. tell me please, where are my mistakes?!

```
values = [(2, 5), (5, 1), (7, 2), (11, 1)]
result = str(f'({i[0]}**{i[1]})' for i in values if i[1] != 1 else f'({i[0]})')
print(result) # (2 ** 5)(5)(7 ** 2)(11)
```

Answer (score 2):

this is a variant:

```
values = [(2, 5), (5, 1), (7, 2), (11, 1)]
result =  ''.join(f'({base} ** {exp})' if exp != 1 else f'({base})' 
                  for base, exp in values)
print(result) # (2 **  5)(5)(7 ** 2)(11)
```

where i use tuple unpacking to assign `base` and `exp` to the items of your list and then [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) (in the form `''.join(...)`) to join the individual terms.

so in the first iteration you get `base=2, exp=5` which will be converted to the string `'(2 **  5)'`; on the second iteration you get `base=5, exp=1`which will be converted to the string `'(5)'` (and so on); then these strings will be joined with `''` (i.e. an empty string) in between.

Answer (score 1):

Place your ternary operator before the list comprehension part:

````
result = "".join([
    f'({i[0]} ** {i[1]})' if i[1] != 1 else f'({i[0]})'
    for i in values 
])
print(result) # (2 ** 5)(5)(7 ** 2)(11)```
````

Comment: you create an unnecessary list in your `join`; a generator expression would do there.

Answer (score 0):

that is my decision. thank to all!

```
result =  ''.join('({} ** {})'.format(i[0], i[1]) if i[1] != 1 else '({})'.format(i[0]) for i in values)
```